# Why can't I printf and scanf value at same time

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main()

{

int rowch,row,*order[1];

char columnch, column;


scanf("%c%d%s%c%d", &columnch, &rowch, &order, &column, &row);

printf("%c %d %s %c %d", columnch, rowch, order, column, row);


return 0;

}
```

Comment: Please state your question *in the question*.

Comment: counterquestion: what kind of input/value would you expect from the user for the address of an array of pointers?

Comment: `%s` requires a `char *`.

Comment: input: a 11 king a 12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong use of `scanf()` format parameter.  Check `scanf()` result.

```
// int ... *order[1];
// scanf("...%s...",...,&order,...);
```

Should be

```
char order[80];  // select size as needed.

if (scanf("%c%d%79s%c%d", &columnch, &rowch, order, &column, &row) != 5) {
  // Handle format error
  exit(1);
}
```

[Edit]

With OP supplied sample input of "a 11 king a 12" recommend a different format: spaces before `%c`.

```
" %c%d%79s %c%d"
```